# How to show php variable output on an image

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I have javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var abc = document.createElement('script');
    var bhs_id = "yvw3lwc1tnvq670ybzprm8uhuhjrider";
    bhs.src = "//example.com/abc.php?site=" + bhs_id + "";    
    document.head.appendChild(bhs);
</script>
```

which add data to database, and i have made a simple php file which output online users corresponding to site id which is bhs_id which is different for different website in above script.

As the above script insert data into database. Besides i want to show online visitors that particular website on an image in the same way as on website whos.amung.us

Can somebody guide me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It really need to be an image?

You could create an piece of html like:

```
<div class="counter-wrapper">
    <img src="your-counter-image.png">
    <span><!-- Print your counter value here --></span>
</div>
```

and style it using css:

```
div.counter-wrapper {
    position: relative;
}

div.counter-wrapper > span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%; // Adjust this values according to your image.
    left: 50%; // The value can be in %, px, cm, rem, etc.
}
```

Comment: where to get php output which i want to show on image

Comment: The value is already inside your script. You can update your response to contain a javascript that search for the span and change it contents.

Comment: can you explain